# Blender to Unity3D wrong materials

Tags: unity-game-engine, modeling, blender

I'm modeling a new map for My game in Blender. In Blender all textures are Unwraped to models and they looking as they should, but when I export them to Unity (export to fbx or just import the blend file doesn't change anything), I checked the "Swap UVs", but some textures - materials have wrong position, for example
[image: pic1]
 that's the result of my work in Blender.
and that's what I get in Unity : [image: pic2]
 and with the wrong materials it create empty diffuse materials which are named "None" + random texture name [image: pic3]
. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are UV unmapping this model in blender incorrectly.
Depending on the size of the texture Unity uses in relation to your game, you need to increase or decrease your UV map size.
For example
I have a brick wall that I want to texture
Unity is using 360x240 sized texture for my map models of maps
 (those deminsions are whack but bear with me)
If I were you and doing it incorrectly,
 I would be trying to fit your wall on a texture size that Unity isn't using for your game
So Steps to solve this problem

Method A

1. Highlight your model you wish to texture
2. Press U
3. Select Smart UV map
   Attempt to place in unity again

Method B
(this method will not work for detail specific textures but seeing as yours is a more cement texture I do not belive it matters where the texture is as long as it shows.

1. Inside blender UV unmappping tool, you can increase or decrease the size of the map or increase the UVMap ratio 
   2.process of elimination, figure out if u need to increase the size, to show more 
   or decrease it to show less 
   then even it out untill it fits reasonably

That method is the choppy way I don't recommend if you are in a hurry

Method C

1.Simply don't use blender for UV unmappping 
2.The UV unmappping tool in blender are not the best and external programs may be nessescary....
I'm sorry if these methods do not help :( Good Luck :)